# How i can to add option to select in Cell properties react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a problem when i use Select in Cell property 
i tried this code. in console.log loop work and have value in val but not render option to select

```
{
         Header: "last update",
         id : "appoint",
         accessor: "appoint",
         Cell: row => (
               <select>
                   {
                         row.row.appoint.map((val,key)=>{
                             <option value={val.work_start_date_full}>val.work_text</option>
                         })
                    }
                 </select>)
}
```

then i tried. it . loop work ( try in console.log ) but display val is not defined

```
{
        Header: "last update",
        id : "appoint",
        accessor: "appoint",
        Cell: row => (
               <select>
                      row.row.appoint.map((val,key)=>{
                            <option value={val.work_start_date_full}>val.work_text</option>
                       }) 
               </select>
         )
}
```

example data in appoint

```
appoint : [
             {work_no : xxxx, work_txt:"xxxxxxxxxxxx' },
             {work_no : yyyy, work_txt:"yyyyyyyyyyyy' },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing with this:

```
 <option value={val.work_start_date_full}>{val.work_text}</option>
```

also, is this right?:

```
"yyyyyyyyyyyy'
```

or it should be?:

```
"yyyyyyyyyyyy" or 'yyyyyyyyyyyy'
```

Let me know if it helps...